# Best approach for aligning 3 square images, 1 large and 2 small, the large left-adjacent to the 2 small stacked on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have three square images that are supposed to be 800 x 800 in width/height and the other two smaller ones in 400 x 400. The 800 pixel image should be on the left and aligned to the right would be the two smaller images stacked on top of each other.

A picture should help explain:

[image]

My bootstrap 4 related HTML is like so:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <img src="modernforms/src/img/main.jpg" width=700 height=700 />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <img src="modernforms/src/img/side.jpg" width=350 height=350 />
                <img src="modernforms/src/img/sidetwo.jpg" width="350" height="350" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the problem I face is how to make this fragile layout mobile friendly when user resizes. What I would like is for these squares to be full width `col-12` one on top of the other but I can't seem to make it happen. Am I misunderstanding a lot here? Or is this impossible? Thank you.

Comment: They way you have it could work with some css edits, but a much easier solution is to nest another row inside the outter row. I added how i would write the code as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to have one row with 2 columns, then in the second column nest another row with always col-12 images. Here is what the code should look like. Also i would take out the width and height attributes from images and just let the col class handle that. You can add img-fluid to the class of the image to help with image resizing.

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
   <img src="big picture here" />
 </div>

 <div class="col-12 col-lg-5>
   <div class="row">

     <div class="col-12">
       <img src="small image 1 here"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
       <img src="small image 2 here"/>
     </div>

   </div> <!-- end of nested row-->
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of main row -->
```

Comment: One question, how to remove spacing between main image and two side images?

Comment: Also, bonus quesition, is it possible to have all 3 span across equally for tablet sized devices? That would be great. Thank you.

Comment: The spacing is going to be there from margins and padding given by some of the bootstrap classes. So you will need to target each element that is creating space between these elements and give it padding:0; and margin:0; -- make sure your css file is called *after* the bootstrap cdn so that your css overrides bootstraps

Comment: all 3 equal in tablet is achievable too. But i dont understand your question clearly. Do you want a mobile phone to show them all on top of each other at full width, then on a tablet, all 3 next to each other at the same size, then on a computer large next to the stacked 2 images ?  - if you would like to message me directly and give a more detailed example of what you are trying to do i can help you write it.

Comment: i have been using bootstrap for 3 years so there are a lot of people better than me still! but you will get there! it just takes using it often and soon you will be a pro!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want yo remove some of the bootstrap complexety, you can "easly" do this with **CSS grid**, in this case you want to create a grid which is **2x2** and make the first image occuppy the two rows, while the other images, only occupy 1 row, to accomplish the desktop version.

On mobile, you just need to change the way the the grid is structured to **1x1**, so that all images are one under another. Take a look at the following example:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;

  --grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  --grid-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.grid-container{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: var(--grid-rows);
  grid-template-columns: var(--grid-columns);
}

.big-img{
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    --grid-columns: 1fr;
    --grid-rows: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
      <img class="big-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1133957/pexels-photo-1133957.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
      <img src="https://www.thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Beautiful-Wallpapers-14.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/beautiful-dandelion-flower-flying-feathers-colorful-bokeh-background-macro-shot-summer-nature-scene-beautiful-dandelion-147400154.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```